# Split a word to letters so letters would become a key in a dictionary. [Python]

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have made a morse code translator where you can put in a letter to print out the corresponding code and vice versa. However, the program is only limited for accepting one letter at a time. How can I make it accept a word? Here's my code:

```
MorseCode = {'.-':'A',
            '-...':'B',
            '-.-.':'C',
            '-..':'D',
            '.':'E',
            '..-.':'F',
            '--.':'G',
            '....':'H',
            '..':'I',
            '.---':'J',
            '-.-':'K',
            '.-..':'L',
            '--':'M',
            '-.':'N',
            '---':'O',
            '.--.':'P',
            '--.-':'Q',
            '.-.':'R',
            '...':'S',
            '-':'T',
            '..-':'U',
            '...-':'V',
            '.--':'W',
            '-..-':'X',
            '-.--':'Y',
            '--..':'Z',
            '.----':1,
            '..---':2,
            '...--':3,
            '....-':4,
            '.....':5,
            '-....':6,
            '--...':7,
            '---..':8,
            '----.':9,
            '-----':0
}

letters_to_morse = {letter: code for code, letter in MorseCode.items()}

print "Type 'help' for the morse code."
print "Type 'end' to exit the program.\n"
while True:
    code = raw_input("Enter code:")
    if code in MorseCode:
        print MorseCode[code]
    elif code in letters_to_morse:
        print letters_to_morse[code]
```

The question is: Is there a way to put in a word and splits that word to each letter so each letter would become a key to the dictionary to print out the value?
Example: the word 'boy' would be split into 'b','o','y' and then the program would print out: -... --- -.--

What I tried so far:

```
MorseCode = {'.-':'A',
            '-...':'B',
            '-.-.':'C',
            '-..':'D',
            '.':'E',
            '..-.':'F',
            '--.':'G',
            '....':'H',
            '..':'I',
            '.---':'J',
            '-.-':'K',
            '.-..':'L',
            '--':'M',
            '-.':'N',
            '---':'O',
            '.--.':'P',
            '--.-':'Q',
            '.-.':'R',
            '...':'S',
            '-':'T',
            '..-':'U',
            '...-':'V',
            '.--':'W',
            '-..-':'X',
            '-.--':'Y',
            '--..':'Z',
            '.----':1,
            '..---':2,
            '...--':3,
            '....-':4,
            '.....':5,
            '-....':6,
            '--...':7,
            '---..':8,
            '----.':9,
            '-----':0
}

Inverse_Dictionary = {v:k for k,v in Dictionary.iteritems()}

while True:
    x = raw_input("Enter:")
    for letter in list(x):
        if letter in Dictionary:
            print (Dictionary[letter])
        elif letter in Inverse_Dictionary:
            print(Inverse_Dictionary[letter])
        else:
            print("Not good")
```

It worked. When I typed 'BOY' it printed out: -... --- -.-- but when I tried to enter -... --- -.--, it keeps printing out "Not good."

anyone can tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
for letter in list(x):
```

To

```
for letter in x.split():
```

Also you got `Inverse_Dictionary = {v:k for k,v in Dictionary.iteritems()}`, however `Dictionary` is undefined, it should be `Inverse_Dictionary = {v:k for k,v in MorseCode.iteritems()}`

Answer (score 0):

list(x) returns a list with character typed . So

```
list(' -... --- -.--,')
```

will return

```
[' ', '-', '.', '.', '.', ' ', '-', '-', '-', ' ', '-', '.', '-', '-', ',']
```

You need a way to diversify your input. For example leave a space between each letter/Morse code and then do:

```
while True:
    x = raw_input("Enter:")
    for letter in x.split(' '):
        if letter in Dictionary:
            print (Dictionary[letter])
        elif letter in Inverse_Dictionary:
            print(Inverse_Dictionary[letter])
        else:
            print("Not good")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
letters_to_morse = {letter: code for code, letter in MorseCode.items()}

string_to_convert = raw_input('Enter message you want to translate to morse...')

trans = ''
for char in string_to_convert:
    if char.isdigit():
        trans = trans + letters_to_morse[int(char)]
    elif char == ' ':
        trans = trans + ' '
    else:
        trans = trans + letters_to_morse[str.upper(char)]


print trans
```

Answer (score 0):

This code does the trick pythonically:

## morse.py

```
>>> def translate(word):
...    inverse_morse = dict({str(v): k for k, v in MorseCode.items()},**{" ":" "})
...    return "".join([inverse_morse[letter.upper()] for letter in word])
>>> print(translate("boy 123"))
-...----.-- .----..---...--
```

Comment: What about spaces and numbers?